# Exception to throw when instance variables are null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm working on making a codebase complaint with a list of PMD rules. These include that you're not allowed to throw or catch `NullPointerException`s. I found this method which requires 2 instance variables to be non-null in order to run. It throws a `NullPointerException` otherwise:

```
public String build() {
if (apiKey == null || url == null) {
    throw new NullPointerException(
            "Cannot build: API key and URL must be set");
}
```

What should it be throwing instead? it seems to me that `NullPointerException` would be the bast call. The only other thing that comes to mind is `IllegalArgumentException`, but these aren't really arguments, so I don't think it really fits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IllegalStateException` springs to mind.

One thing to consider here is whether this should be a checked or an unchecked exception. You could also consider making your own explicit Exception for this case if it can usefully be handled differently from the generic `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: +1 Although Jon Skeet beat you by 10 seconds. I'll be good to you.

Comment: @PaulVargas Yeah, but it's Jon Skeet. Even Chuck Norris can't get an answer in before Jon Skeet: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts

Answer (score 7):

[`IllegalStateException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) seems entirely appropriate here:

> Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time.

That describes the situation reasonably clearly, doesn't it?